# remove characters from string without using string.h library

Tags: c

I am doing a assignment, it asks for removing some characters from string without using the string.h library, this is my code:

```
 int deleteFunc(char chara[100], char a)
{
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 100; i++)
      if (a == chara[i])
       return TRUE;
   else return FALSE;
}
```

I though there are some problems in my deleteFunc , but I dont know how to fix that, any one can help . thank you!

Comment: Do you know how to copy a string without using `strcpy`? Then you know how to solve this too.

Comment: Brief about your problem in the question

Comment: do you mean something like this strcpy(string, pointer); but this requires string.h function

Comment: Implementing your own `strcpy` function is easy. And then it's very easy to add a check for certain characters that you don't want to copy. So start by making ***your own*** implementation of `strcpy`.

Comment: my problem is: input the original string like : qwertyabc  then input the serveral characters want to delete like: eb then ouput is qwrtyac

Comment: ok, I ll try to implement strcpy function, thank you. It is so good if there is any idea for fix my code too;)

Comment: I think gets will return line with end of line. Are you sure you want to remove ends of lines form your text?

Comment: @V-X: The `gets` function should never be used (it's inherently unsafe, and has been removed from the language). `fgets()` does leave the newline `'\n'` character in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please take a look at the below code it might help.

```
int main()
{
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,q;
    char a[20],b[20];
    char *p = malloc(20);
    scanf("%s %s",a,b);
     while(a[i] != '\0')
     {
         j=0;
         q =0;
         while(b[j] != '\0')
         {
            if(a[i] == b[j])
            {
                q  =1;
                break;
            }
            j++;
         }
         if(!q)
         p[k++] = a[i];
         i++;
     }
     p[k] = '\0';
     printf("%s\n",p);
     free(p);
     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`deleteFunc` change to

```
int deleteFunc(char chara[100], char a){
    int i ;
    for ( i = 0 ; i < 100 && chara[i]; i++)//'\0' after the garbage data
        if (a == chara[i])
            return TRUE;
    return FALSE;//If that does not match all of the candidate
}
```

and at main

```
*pointer = '\0';
printf("String after removing is \"%s\"\n", start);//Display prior to release, or written back
```