# String's character delete & Frequency without using library

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to work on a assignment which need to input two string S & str and then deliver three results **(Without using any string library)**:

1.Determine the **number** and **positions** of the given str in S

2.Return S with any possible occurrence of str removed

ex. if S=**aababacd cdefgh** ,
       str=**aba**

The Frequency is **2**, position is **<0,2>**
The Character Delete would be **cd cdefgh**

Attached code is what I have done so far, I can output the Frequency and the position, but now I have few unsolved questions and I have no idea how to implement it.

1.Once I input a string with space in there, ex. abcd efg, the code will implement it immediately, it will not **consider abcd efg as one string** but consider it as **S=abcd and str=efg** , with this problem I cant input a string with blank space to test.

2.How can I output the position like this form: **<0,2>** , because I am using a loop to output the result so it cant not be like that, I was thinking whether I can create an array to store i and then cout it, but I failed.

3.About the character Delete problem, I found one  [similar problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26837643/remove-characters-from-string-without-using-string-h-library), it said if I know how to use strcpy without using library then I would know, but I learned it and I still dont know how to handle this question, I know I can compare these two strings but I dont know how to output S without the str part.I was thinking to change the S into '\0' after loop and output it, but that was totally wrong.

I would be really appreciated if anyone could give me some advice, thank you!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

void CharacterDelete(){

    char S[100], str[100];
    bool match =true;

    cout << "Enter string S :";
    cin >> S;
    cout << "Enter string str :";
    cin>>str;

    for(int i=0; S[i]!='\0'; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; str[j]!='\0';j++){

            if(S[i+j]!=str[j]){

                match=false;
                break;
            }
            if(match){
                S[i+j]='\0';
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<S;//Apparently thats a wrong solution
}

void Frequency(){


    string S,str;
    cout<<"Please input string S"<<endl;
    cin>>S;
    cout<<"Please input string str"<<endl;
    cin>>str;

    int sum=0;


    for (int i=0; i<S.size(); i++)
    {
        if (i + str.size() > S.size()) break;
        bool match=true;
        for (int j=0; j<str.size(); j++)
            if (S[i+j] != str[j])
            {
                match=false;
                break;
        //Once we print blank space and it would implement it immediately?
            }
            if(match)
            {
                sum++;
                cout<<"Start from"<<i<<endl;
                //What if we use an array to store it and then output it?but how to write it?

            }
    }

    cout<<"The Frequency is "<<sum<<endl;
    if(sum==0){
        cout<<"There is no starting point"<<endl;

    }
}

int main() {
    Frequency();
    CharacterDelete();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using local variables S and str. You need to use S and str in main function. Then transfer this variables from main in Frequency() and CharacterDelete.

Delete characters: create new variable then copy there characters without delete-characters.

Output:

```
cout << "<" << num_word << ", " << number << ">\n";
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but I just want to check one thing about the character part, can you give me an example about copy without delete, thank you so much